# How can i get mobile network status?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

First of all I am using android studio 1.5. I want to check GSM/GPRS network coverage? how can i get phone network status?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you'll need these permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

then after that where you want to check the Network status you should use this:

```
boolean isOnline= isNetworkStatusAvialable (getApplicationContext());
```

this will return if the mobile has Network available or not.
hope this is all you need!

> and just to let you know it is already answered on stackoverflow. you
>   should really check if the question is there already or not!

**Happy coding!**

Comment: Thank you Akshay Kulkarni. I'll try this.

Comment: It should work fine as I've been using this method in one of my project and accept the answer to let others know with the similar question that this works! try avoiding duplicate questions. Let me know if there is any trouble